# Recursive MergeSort and counting comparisons

Tags: java

I have written a program that contains 4 sorting methods, selection sort, insertion sort, merge sort, and recursive merge sort. The insertion and selection sort methods run fine and return to me a sorted list and the right amount of comparisons. My merge sort method returns me a sorted list, but my comparisons = 1. My recursive merge sort doesnt even sort the list and also says comparisons = 1. Can anybody help me find my errors? Here is all my code.

```
public class ArraySort {
    private long[] a;                 // ref to array a
    private int nElems;               // number of data items

    public ArraySort(int max) {       // constructor
       a = new long[max];             // create the array
       nElems = 0;                    // no items yet
    }

    public void Clone(ArraySort c) {  // c is another array
       c.nElems = this.nElems;                                 // Copy nElems
       System.arraycopy(this.a, 0, c.a, 0, this.nElems);       // Copy elements
    }

    public void insert(long value) {  // put element into array
       a[nElems++] = value;           // insert value
    }

    public String toString() {           // displays array contents
       String res="";
       for(int j=0; j<nElems; j++)       // for each element,
          res = res + a[j] + " ";        // append it to res
       return res;
    }

    private int insertOrder(int n, long temp) { // insert temp into a[0..(n-1)]
                  // and keep a[0..n] sorted.
        int count = 0;
        while (n > 0) {
            count++;                       // count next comparison
            if (a[n-1] > temp)   {         // until one is smaller,
               a[n] = a[n-1];              // shift item to right
               --n;                        // go left one position
            } else break;
        }
        a[n] = temp;                      // insert marked item
        return count;
    }

    public int insertionSort() {
        int count = 0;
        for (int n=1; n<nElems; n++)  
            count += insertOrder(n, a[n]);   // insert a[n] into a[0..(n-1)]

        return count;
    } // end insertionSort()

    private void swap(int one, int two) {
       long temp = a[one];
       a[one] = a[two];
       a[two] = temp;
    }

    public int selectionSort() {
       int out, in, max, count=0;

       for(out=nElems-1; out > 0; out--) {  // outer loop
          max = out;                        // max is maximum item's index
          for(in=0; in<out; in++) {          // inner loop
             if(a[in] > a[max] )            // if max is smaller,
                 max = in;                  // we have a new max
             count++;                       // count one comparison
          }
          swap(out, max);                   // swap them
       }  // end for(out)
       return count;
    }  // end selectionSort()

    public int mergeSort() {           // called by main()
        int count = 0;
        long[] workSpace = new long[nElems]; // provides workspace
        recMergeSort(workSpace, 0, nElems-1);
        count++;
        return count;
    }


public int recMergeSort(long[] workSpace, int lowerBound,
        int upperBound) {

    int count = 0;

    if(lowerBound == upperBound)            // if range is 1,
        return 1;

    // find midpoint
    int mid = (lowerBound+upperBound) / 2;

    recMergeSort(workSpace, lowerBound, mid);   // sort low half

    recMergeSort(workSpace, mid+1, upperBound);  // sort high half


    merge(workSpace, lowerBound, mid+1, upperBound); // merge them
    count++;
    return count;

}  // end else
  // end recMergeSort()


private int merge(long[] workSpace, int lowPtr,
        int highPtr, int upperBound)
{
    int j = 0;                             // workspace index

    int lowerBound = lowPtr;

    int mid = highPtr-1;

    int n = upperBound-lowerBound+1;       // # of items

    int count = 0;

    while(lowPtr <= mid && highPtr <= upperBound)

        if( a[lowPtr] < a[highPtr] ) {
            workSpace[j++] = a[lowPtr++];
            count++;
        }

        else {
            workSpace[j++] = a[highPtr++];
            count++;
        }

        while(lowPtr <= mid)
            workSpace[j++] = a[lowPtr++];

        count++;


        while(highPtr <= upperBound)
            workSpace[j++] = a[highPtr++];

        count++;

        for(j=0; j<n; j++)

           a[lowerBound+j] = workSpace[j];

        return count;
    }  // end merge()
}
```

The methods are being called from here...

```
import java.util.*;

public class SortComparison {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       int count, maxSize = 20;      // array size
       ArraySort arr, carr;           // reference to array
       arr = new ArraySort(maxSize);  // create the arrays
       carr = new ArraySort(maxSize);

       // insert some random numbers
              Random generator = new Random();
       for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            arr.insert(Math.abs(generator.nextInt())%maxSize);
       }

       System.out.println("Before sort: " + arr);                // display items

       arr.Clone(carr);
       count = carr.insertionSort();          // insertion-sort a clone of arr
       System.out.println("Insert sort: " + carr + " comparions=" + count);                  

       arr.Clone(carr);
       count = carr.selectionSort();          // selection-sort a clone of arr
       System.out.println("Select sort: " + carr + " comparions=" + count); 

       arr.Clone(carr);
       count = carr.mergeSort();
       System.out.println("Merge sort: " + carr + " comparions=" + count);

       arr.Clone(carr);
       count = carr.recMergeSort(null, maxSize, maxSize);
       System.out.println("RecMerge sort: " + carr + " comparions=" + count);

  }  // end main()

}  // end class SortComparison
```

and when the program is run this is the output i receive...

```
Before sort: 3 2 4 7 17 11 3 0 14 6 8 7 12 15 0 0 9 4 7 16 
Insert sort: 0 0 0 2 3 3 4 4 6 7 7 7 8 9 11 12 14 15 16 17  comparions=94
Select sort: 0 0 0 2 3 3 4 4 6 7 7 7 8 9 11 12 14 15 16 17  comparions=190
Merge sort: 0 0 0 2 3 3 4 4 6 7 7 7 8 9 11 12 14 15 16 17  comparions=1
RecMerge sort: 3 2 4 7 17 11 3 0 14 6 8 7 12 15 0 0 9 4 7 16  comparions=1
```

Can anybody help me fix this!?

---

I dont know why my recursive merge sort method wont sort the list. And why the comparisons = 1 for the last two.

Comment: Could we clean up this question? It's sort of hard to tell what you're asking...

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a homework, I'll only show how to fix `mergeSort()`:

```
public int mergeSort() {
    int count = 0;
    long[] workSpace = new long[nElems];
    count += recMergeSort(workSpace, 0, nElems-1); // Add the comparisons executed there
    return count;
}
```

You need to fix `recMergeSort()` in a similar fashion.

I guess that you think of `count` as of a global variable.  But it's not.  In all your sorting methods `count` is a local variable, which is not visible outside the scope of the method.  Therefore, if you modify the `count` variable inside `recMergeSort()` it will not be automatically affect the (other) `count` variable inside `mergeSort()`.  A natural way to "send" the count from (called) `recMergeSort()` to (calling) `mergeSort()` is through `return count`, as you correctly did.  Unfortunately, you did not use the result which `recMergeSort()` returned.

One last thing, since maybe I wasn't clear enough: even if you recursively call `recMergeSort()` from `recMergeSort()`, still the `count` variable in the caller is different from the `count` variable in the callee.  So even if you do recursive calls, still the called method needs to pass the result through `return` and the calling method needs to pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

The following is your `mergeSort()` method:

```
public int mergeSort() {           // called by main()
    int count = 0;
    long[] workSpace = new long[nElems]; // provides workspace
    recMergeSort(workSpace, 0, nElems-1);
    count++;
    return count;
}
```

This method returns 1 because you create a variable called `count`, increment it once *and only once* after calling `recMergeSort`, and then return it. `recMergeSort` contains another local variable called `count`, but this local variable is *completely separate* to that in `mergeSort`. The `count++` lines in `recMergeSort` have no effect on `count` within `mergeSort`.

Your `merge` and `recMergeSort` methods both return the number of comparisons made, but you don't do anything with the returned values.  To count the total number of comparisons, get rid of the `count++` line in the above, and replace the line

```
recMergeSort(workSpace, 0, nElems-1);
```

with

```
count += recMergeSort(workSpace, 0, nElems-1);
```

You will also need to make similar changes to the various method calls in `recMergeSort`.

Why is the last line of your output above not sorting the list?  Well, you are making the following method call:

```
count = carr.recMergeSort(null, maxSize, maxSize);
```

Your `recMergeSort` method begins as follows:

```
public int recMergeSort(long[] workSpace, int lowerBound,
        int upperBound) {

    int count = 0;

    if(lowerBound == upperBound)            // if range is 1,
        return 1;

    // rest of method omitted
}
```

You are clearly calling `recMergeSort` with the `lowerBound` and `upperBound` parameters the same.  As a result, the method is returning `1`, because you explicitly asked it to.

Comment: Thanks Pourquoi Litytestdata, but what parameters can i use instead of maxSize and maxSize to give me the lowest and highest entries in the array?

Comment: The following works: `count = carr.recMergeSort(new long[maxSize], 0, maxSize - 1);`.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, just post the relevant code.  We don't necessarily need to see all the methods that work.

It is possible to make a recursive sort algorithm using only one method (and personally, I think it would be easier if you did).  You're very much on the right track, at any rate.  But look at mergeSort() - you declare count = 0, do your recursion, add 1 to count, and then return it.  The problem you're having is that you only increment count once, when you should be giving it the value returned by recMergeSort().  See my in-line comments for solutions.

```
public int mergeSort() {           // called by main() 
    int count = 0;

    long[] workSpace = new long[nElems]; // provides workspace
        /*
           recMergeSort() returns an integer, but you do not assign it to anything.
        */
    recMergeSort(workSpace, 0, nElems-1);
    count++;
        /* Instead, try something like 
               count = recMergeSort(workspace, 0, nElms-1);
               return count;
        */
return count;
}


public int recMergeSort(long[] workSpace, int lowerBound, int upperBound) { int count = 0;
    if(lowerBound == upperBound) // if range is 1, return 1;
    // find midpoint int mid = (lowerBound+upperBound) / 2;
    recMergeSort(workSpace, lowerBound, mid); // sort low half
    recMergeSort(workSpace, mid+1, upperBound); // sort high half
    merge(workSpace, lowerBound, mid+1, upperBound); // merge them count++; return count; } // end else // end recMergeSort()
    private int merge(long[] workSpace, int lowPtr, int highPtr, int upperBound) { int j = 0; // workspace index
    int lowerBound = lowPtr;
    int mid = highPtr-1;
    int n = upperBound-lowerBound+1; // # of items
    int count = 0;
    while(lowPtr <= mid && highPtr <= upperBound)
    if( a[lowPtr] < a[highPtr] ) {
        workSpace[j++] = a[lowPtr++];
        count++;
    } else {
        workSpace[j++] = a[highPtr++];
        count++; }
    while(lowPtr <= mid)
        workSpace[j++] = a[lowPtr++];
        count++;
    while(highPtr <= upperBound)
        workSpace[j++] = a[highPtr++];
        count++;
    for(j=0; j


                       //AAAAAH! What happened to your For loop???

        a[lowerBound+j] = workSpace[j]; return count; } // end merge()

}
```